# mongodb get entries where id exists multiple times based on count condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection 'bookings' with the following example structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1"),
    "user" : ObjectId("1"),
    "event" : ObjectId("1"),
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("2"),
    "user" : ObjectId("1"),
    "event" : ObjectId("1"),
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("3"),
    "user" : ObjectId("2"),
    "event" : ObjectId("1"),
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4"),
    "user" : ObjectId("3"),
    "event" : ObjectId("1"),
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5"),
    "user" : ObjectId("4"),
    "event" : ObjectId("2"),
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6"),
    "user" : ObjectId("1"),
    "event" : ObjectId("2"),
}
```

I cant figure out a query that shows all "event" id's in which the same "user" id appears multiple times. something like this:

```
{
  "event": 1,
  "user": 1,
  "count": 2
}
```

Does not have to be this exact output, in other words I just want a way to have a query to get all events for which the same "user" id has more than one entry in this "bookings" collection.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do grouping and filtering.

In SQL it would be just as simple as

```
SELECT count(*) as cc, user, event FROMM t1 GROUP BY user, event HAVING cc > 1
```

In MongoDB, you can use the aggregation framework to do equivalent stuff.

It does the same in 3 different steps in the pipeline: group, filter, project.

```
db.mycollection.aggregate( [
   { $group: { _id: { user: "$user", event: "$event", }, count: { $sum: 1 } } },
   { $match: { count: { $gt: 1 } } },
   { $project: { _id: 0, 
                 userId: "$_id. user",
                 event: "$_id.event",
                 count: 1
               }
   }
] )
```

This documentation can help you to understand deeper: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/

Comment: Ah ok, I had problems starting by getting the grouping right. Your solution does it, thank you!